# jQuery Simple text change on image hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a script for changing text on image hover. This is the HTML in simple version:

```
  <section id="#first">
    <div class="img-1"></div>
    <div class="img-2"></div>
  </section>

  <section id="#second">
    <div class="text-1"></div>
    <div class="text-2"></div>
  </section>
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.img-1').hover(
     function(){ $('.text-1').addClass('text-1-active') },
     function(){ $('.img-1').addClass('img-1-active') },
     function(){ $('.text-2').removeClass('text-2-active') },
     function(){ $('.img-2').removeClass('img-2-active') }
)
$('.img-2').hover(
     function(){ $('.text-2').addClass('text-2-active') },
     function(){ $('.img-2').addClass('img-2-active') },
     function(){ $('.img-1').removeClass('img-1-active') },
     function(){ $('.text-1').removeClass('text-1-active') }
)
```

});

Can't change the HTML structure. The classes do get added but don't get removed.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/)**

Comment: [RTM](http://api.jquery.com/hover/); `.hover` expects one or two arguments, you are passing four.

Comment: Perhaps, very new at jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:) actually this is all you need: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/13/)

```
$("#first [class^=img-]").hover(function() {
    $('#second .text-'+ this.className.replace(/\D/g,'')).toggle();
});
```

---

If you want to toggle classes? Nothing simpler: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/14/)

```
$("#first [class^=img-]").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("wow");
    $('#second .text-'+ this.className.replace(/\D/g,'')).toggleClass("wow");
});
```

To explain the above, you just need to find out the *number* of the hovered element and reference-by number the needed `.text-`*N* element.

Also this `<section id="#first">`, that `#first` is **not the way** to set an ID to an HTML element.
Use simply `<section id="first">`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to pass four separate callback functions, rather than a single callback that executes all the necessary code.

Here is what you want:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.img-1').hover(
          function(){ 
             $('.text-1').addClass('text-1-active');
             $('.img-1').addClass('img-1-active');
             $('.text-2').removeClass('text-2-active');
             $('.img-2').removeClass('img-2-active');
          }
    )
    $('.img-2').hover(
         function(){ 
             $('.text-2').addClass('text-2-active');
             $('.img-2').addClass('img-2-active');
             $('.img-1').removeClass('img-1-active');
             $('.text-1').removeClass('text-1-active');
         }
    )   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are handing the `hover` event a list of functions. Just send it one that does eveything.

I.E.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.img-1').hover(
        function() {
            $('.text-1').addClass('text-1-active');
            $('.img-1').addClass('img-1-active');
            $('.text-2').removeClass('text-2-active');
            $('.img-2').removeClass('img-2-active');
        }
    );
    $('.img-2').hover(
        function() {
            $('.text-2').addClass('text-2-active');
            $('.img-2').addClass('img-2-active');
            $('.img-1').removeClass('img-1-active');
            $('.text-1').removeClass('text-1-active');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you use the `.hover` function wrongly, it should only accept `2 arguments` which is for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You should be using it like this

```
$("selector").hover(
    function(){
        // mouseenter function
    },
    function(){
        // mouseleave function
    }
});
```

and second you don't need to use too long `class name` to to decide it's active or not, hence you can use it to diferentiate it like this `text-1 active` and `text-2 active`, so you can write it like this in `jQuery`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.img-1').hover(
         function(){ $('.text-1').addClass('active') },
         function(){ $('.text-1, .text-2').removeClass('active') }
    )
    $('.img-2').hover(
         function(){ $('.text-2').addClass('active') },
         function(){ $('.text-1, .text-2').removeClass('active') }
    )

});
```

and `CSS`

```
.text-1, 
.text-2{
    display:none;
}
.text-1.active, 
.text-2.active{
    display:block;
}
```

here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/3/) with the optimized way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you don't need classes to show and hide the text, use .show() and .hide() to take care of it, in the original js you're passing 4 functions to the hover event whereas only 2 are needed, one executes when the element is hovered and the second one when mouse exits the element causing hover event to stop.

Here's the modified js, take a look at the fiddle too -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.img-1').hover(
         function(){ 
             $('.text-1').show(); 
             $('.text-2').hide();
         },
         function(){ 
             $('.text-1, .text-2').hide(); 
         }
    );
    $('.img-2').hover(
         function(){ 
             $('.text-2').show(); 
             $('.text-1').hide(); 
         },
         function(){ 
             $('.text-1, .text-2').hide(); 
         }
    );

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/7/)

I'm basically hiding both texts on exit, if you want one text block to always stay visible you can hide the other one in hover 'exit' function. Here's the fiddle for that -
http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/9/

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption of what you're looking for...but try this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.img-1').mouseover(function () {
        $('.text-1').addClass('text-1-active');
        $('.img-1').addClass('img-1-active')
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('.text-1').removeClass('text-1-active');
        $('.img-1').removeClass('img-1-active');
    });

    $('.img-2').mouseover(function () {
        $('.text-2').addClass('text-2-active');
        $('.img-2').addClass('img-2-active')
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $('.text-2').removeClass('text-2-active');
        $('.img-2').removeClass('img-2-active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your assumption makes sense; however, you can still use `.hover(fn, fn)` function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.img-1').hover(function(){
     $('.text-1').toggleClass('text-1-active');
     $('.img-1').toggleClass('img-1-active');
     $('.text-2').toggleClass('text-2-active');
     $('.img-2').toggleClass('img-2-active');
});
$('.img-2').hover(function(){
     $('.text-2').toggleClass('text-2-active');
     $('.img-2').toggleClass('img-2-active'); 
     $('.img-1').toggleClass('img-1-active'); 
     $('.text-1').toggleClass('text-1-active');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.img-1').hover(
         function(){
             $('.text-1').toggleClass('text-1-active');
             $('.img-1').toggleClass('img-1-active'); 

         }
    )
    $('.img-2').hover(
         function(){ 
             $('.text-2').toggleClass('text-2-active');
          $('.img-2').toggleClass('img-2-active');
         }
    )

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w4mLtec8/10/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what's to be done, the approach itself used to solve the problem could be better.  Basically, use CSS to your advantage.  Here, I've reduced the number of times we call JQuery by taking a little time to set up the HTML and CSS.

1. Tag the corresponding text div with a number
2. Put the same number in a data attribute so the item to hover knows which text it's associated with
3. I believe the intent is to have one text hover active at a time, so we can simple remove all 'active'.  Naturally, we'd one to restrict the selector here to only pull text hovers, but you get the idea.

   ```
   //Javascript Code

   $('.img').hover( function() {
           var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
           $('.text').removeClass('active');
           $('.text[data-name="'+name+'"]').addClass('active');
    });
   ```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkL9uo0k/1/