# JavaScript change image and text when hovered using mouseover and eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to make an image replace another in a fixed position while also changing the color style of the text at the same time. The image and the text needs to change when one or the other is being hovered over by the user. I have the image and text in a div and attempted to use an eventlistener to change the objects.

HTML:

```
<div id="dequestimg">
    <p style="font-size: 75%; float: left; font-weight: bold">Delete Requests:</p>
    <img src="dequestbutton.png"/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addeventlistener("mouseover", mouseover);
document.addeventlistener("mouseout", mouseout);

        function mouseover() {
            document.getelementbyid("dequestimg").style.color = "red";
            document.getelementbyid("dequestimg").getelementsbytagname("img") = "dequestbuttonhover.png";
        }

        function mouseout() {kossa
            document.getelementbyid("dequestimg").style.color = "black";
            document.getelementbyid("dequestimg").getelementsbytagname("img") = "dequestbutton.png";
        }
```

I am new to JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [image change on mouse hover on particular part of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557005/image-change-on-mouse-hover-on-particular-part-of-image)

Comment: You need to check your function names (i,e. `addEventListener()`, `getElementById()`)  JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690977/jquery-simple-text-change-on-image-hover)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759080/change-image-on-hover-with-transition-using-javascript)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775662/change-images-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many points here

- You have an unexpected string in your JavaScript making it invalid: `kossa`
- JavaScript is case-sensitive, you have to use the correct casing in the function names: `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName`
- You can define a variable at the top to select your `div`
- You should probably give the `img` element an id as well so you can select it separately
- You need to set the `src` property of the image once it's selected, you can't just assign it as a string

Here's a working example

HTML index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="dequestimg">
      <p style="font-size: 75%; float: left; font-weight: bold">
        Delete Requests:
      </p>
      <img id="image" src="dequestbutton.png" />
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript index.js

```
const div = document.getElementById("dequestimg");
const img = document.getElementById("image");

document.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseover);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseout);

function mouseover() {
  div.style.color = "red";
  img.src = "dequestbuttonhover.png";
}

function mouseout() {
  div.style.color = "black";
  img.src = "dequestbutton.png";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not know where those spelling mistakes in my code came from when I last looked at it. I tried doing something similar to what you did but from using your code I found out that event listeners do not work in the internal browser that I use in Visual Studios. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Ariolous You should check out [eslint](https://eslint.org/). It'll catch a lot of these errors in Visual Studio Code for you! Even better if you use TypeScript with it.